# How can I do join in hive with array datatype?

Tags: bigdata, hiveql

I have employee table which have employee id as int, employee name as string and department id as array of integer data type as the columns. Give below are the records for the Employee table.

```
employee5.empid employee5.empname       employee5.deptid
1       Emp1    [2,3,1,4]
2       Emp2    [5,2,3,4]
3       Emp3    [1,4,2,3]
4       Emp4    [5,3,4,1]
5       Emp5    [1,2,3,4]
6       Emp6    [5,3,1,2]
7       Emp7    [3,2,4,5]
8       Emp8    [1,4,2,3]
9       Emp9    [5,2,3,1]
10      Emp10   [2,4,3,5]
```

I also have the department table which have department id as int, department name as string and department location as string columns. Give below are the records for the department table.

```
department.deptid       department.deptname     department.location
1       IT      Delhi
2       Support Bangalore
3       HR      Pune
4       Finance Mumbai
5       Call Center     Mysore
```

As I am new to the hive, please help me in displaying the employee name and his corresponding department using the hive join.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested however, this is might work.

First, you need to explode the array into multiple rows and then need the join, I don't think is a direct way to join.

```
select * from   
    (select empid, empname, dept_id from employee5 lateral view explode(deptid) d as dept_id) emp 
    join 
    department
    on 
    department. deptid = emp.dept_id
```